# Yii2 how to hide module name in url?

Tags: url, module, yii2, yii-url-manager

I need some help with UrlManager in Yii2.
I have blog application. There is module called 'blog'. There is BlogController with index action. To run it i must run url like this `localhost/myblog/web/blog/blog/index`
and
`localhost/myblog/web/blog/blog/post?id=4` (for action post).
My settings in web.php are like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => [
        //'<action:(blog|index|)>' => 'blog/blog/index',
        //'/' => 'blog/blog/index'
        ]
    ],
```

I have tried run with line that commented but with no success.
How to configure it to have urls like this `localhost/myblog/web/index` and `localhost/myblog/web/post?id=4` ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

"**urlManager**" alone can not help you. You need to use .htaccess. Then it will work how you want. Please copy bellow codes in you .htaccess. The .htaccess you should put in your root folder.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
  </IfModule>

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
  RewriteRule . index.php
```

Hope this will help. Thanks.